# Conversion to Dalvin format failed with error 1, several methods tried

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dalvik

I want to export my .apk file, but I'm always getting the error message: Conversion to Dalvin format failed with error 1.

I tried to clean up my cache, remove all the libraries (exepted the android x.y), I even started to delete my classes, because I read, that this error is because some classes cannot be convertet to that dalvik thing.

what do I have to do? :(

Comment: post your console output and/or your logcat. This error can happen for lots of reasons.

Comment: Try increase the memory allocated in eclipse.ini to this: -Xms128m -Xmx512m or something higher.

Comment: I put it on1024. no solution. i don't exactly know how to write the logcat in here. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]This usually happens because of library conflicts and resource issues, If you have already tried clean up. Check the dependencies, make sure you check if you have duel dependency for android API 4 jar

Comment: I have added a picture, in this i was getting the same error as you so i clicked on every depended library and it worked, best of luck

Comment: Thank you. I got it, don't know why, but I gor it.. did the same as you.

Comment: I am happy, I have to tell you i got that issues again an hour ago. cleaned the project and it did work. :)